# How to find the running time of these two functions?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm familiar with the big O notation and the running time and most of the time I can recognize the running time of an algorithm but I'm not sure with this one. 
I'm dealing with a tree here.

**First method:**

```
static boolean containsData(TreeNode treeRoot, String data) {
    if(treeRoot == null)
        return false;
    if(data.equals(treeRoot.data))
        return (true);
    else if((data.compareTo(treeRoot.data))<0)
        return(containsData(treeRoot.left, data));
    else
        return(containsData(treeRoot.right, data));
}
```

**Second method:**

```
static boolean containsData2(TreeNode treeRoot,String data){
    if (treeRoot != null) {
        if (treeRoot.data.contains(data)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return containsData2(treeRoot.left,data) || containsData2(treeRoot.right,data); 
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

I would say that both methods are **O(n)** I can not see how one of them would be **O(log(n))**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods have a worst case running time of O(n) if the tree is not balanced.

The first would run in O(log n) if the tree is balanced.

The second method would still need O(n) even for balanced tree since it traverses both subtrees if the record is found in the right half. It actually does a full scan of all records in sorting order until the record is found. The actual run time depends on the size of the record. A small record will be found faster, a large record will need O(n). The average is O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Both of these methods essentially do the same thing, which is traverse the tree looking for a certain item.  Both methods go left or right in search for the item, and keep doing so until reaching the end of the tree.  As @Sumeet already mentioned, we can't really give you an exact Big-O running time, because we don't know whether the trees are balanced.  In the case of balanced binary trees, the search time for *both* methods should be `O(lgn)`.  However, in the case of a maximally unbalanced tree, both the height *and* number of elements would be `n`, and therefore the search time would be `O(n)`.  If you can clarify the types of trees, we might be able to narrow down an exact running time.

Comment: Tnx, for the extended explanation.

Comment: Why would it be O(nlgn),  a single search operation would be O(lgn) for balanced search trees.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Typo, my apologies.

Comment: The second case is O(n) regardless of whether the tree is balanced or not; see comments on Sumeet's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your first method would be **O(n)** if the underlying tree is **not balanced** and the case would occur when **all data is inserted in either ascending order or descending order**.

It would be **O(logn)**, if **the underlying tree is balanced like Red Black Trees, AVL trees** regardless of the data and its insertion order.

Your second method would be **O(n)** for unbalanced tree and for balanced tree it would be **O(n)** only when the tree does not contain the given data, cause your second method ends up traversing the entire tree in such case. If it does contain, then time would always be **O(logn)**

Comment: Tnx, I just needed a confirmation, I was unsure, don't know why.

Comment: @eugen_sunic You should also try by veryfying when you are not sure. See why it would be O(n) in case of ascending or descending order.

Comment: The second method always takes O(n), even for a balanced tree, See my answer for details.

Comment: Still not fully correct, O(log n) is never achieved even if the record is found.

Comment: The second approach always searches the entire tree (left and right branches), it doesn't compare first . Because it uses the shortcut `||` operator, if the tree is balanced, then it will only search the whole tree half of the time but factors get dropped in the big-O notation so the second case is O(n) (and not O(logn) as this answer says)

Comment: @Henry , There is || operator used not && used, meaning if the left subtree contains the data, then the right subtree is not even touched.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt There is || operator used not && used, meaning if the left subtree contains the data, then the right subtree is not even touched

Comment: yes, but all records with a smaller key are traversed. This gives an O(n) runtime on average

Comment: @SumeetSingh Yes, that is what I'm saying. That might reduce the average time taken to something like 1/2 n or 3/4 n but that's still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

if the tree have n cells, then you are going on `O(n)` (just all of them, once), and this is the right answer. don't confuse the `Height` of the tree, that can be `O(log n)` if the tree is balanced.